# How can i add a PolicyRule using kubectl patch to existing Role

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, argo-workflows

I have the following error message:

> User "system:serviceaccount:qserv:argo-workflow" cannot create resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "qserv"

Here is the related `Role`:

```
kubectl describe role argo-workflows-workflow
Name:         argo-workflows-workflow
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: argo-workflows
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: qserv
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  pods       []                 []              [get watch patch]
  pods/log   []                 []              [get watch]
```

Could you please provide the correct `kubectl patch` command which would allow the `argo-workflows-workflow` role to create `Jobs`?

Answer (score 2):

This command does the job and allow to run the argo workflow successfully:

```
kubectl patch roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io argo-workflows-workflow --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/rules/-", "value": {"apiGroups": ["batch"],"resources": ["jobs"],"verbs": ["create", "get", "watch"]} }]
```